I get the error "ImportError: cannot import name 'model_validator' from 'pydantic'"
I recently switched from the trial version of PyCharm Pro to the Community Edition and started experiencing errors in my Python project using aiogram. There were no issues before the switch.
Steps I've taken:

Updated aiogram from 3.0.0 to 3.4.1.
Checked the package versions using pip show aiogram, pip show pydantic.

The error appears only in the Community Edition of PyCharm, not in the Pro version. Here's the error message:
    from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict, model_validator
ImportError: cannot import name 'model_validator' from 'pydantic' (C:\Users\shock\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pydantic\__init__.cp39-win_amd64.pyd)

code:
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, BigInteger, String, DateTime, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import datetime
Base = declarative_base()

class UserPhoto(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_photos'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(BigInteger, unique=True)
    photos_sent = Column(Integer, default=0)
    processing = Column(Boolean, default=False)
class UserLanguage(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_languages'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(BigInteger, unique=True, nullable=False)
    language_code = Column(String(8), nullable=False)
class UserActivity(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_activity'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(BigInteger, unique=True, nullable=False)
    first_interaction = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    last_interaction = Column(DateTime, onupdate=datetime.datetime.utcnow)


engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://User:password@localhost/telegram_bot_ai_photo')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

version:
Name: aiogram
Version: 3.4.1
Summary: Modern and fully asynchronous framework for Telegram Bot API
Home-page:
Author:
Author-email: Alex Root Junior <jroot.junior@gmail.com>
License:
Location: c:\users\shock\pycharmprojects\bot\.venv\lib\site-packages
Requires: aiofiles, aiohttp, certifi, magic-filter, pydantic, typing-extensions
Required-by:
(.venv) PS C:\Users\shock\PycharmProjects\bot> pip show pydantic
Name: pydantic
(.venv) PS C:\Users\shock\PycharmProjects\bot> pip show pydantic
Name: pydantic
Version: 2.5.3
Summary: Data validation using Python type hints
Home-page: 
Author: 
Author-email: Samuel Colvin <s@muelcolvin.com>, Eric Jolibois <em.jolibois@gmail.com>, Hasan Ramezani <hasan.r67@gmail.com>, Adrian Garcia Badaracco <1755071+adriangb@users.noreply.github.com>, Terrence Dorsey <terry@pydantic.dev>, David Montague <david@pydantic.dev>, Serge Matveenko <lig@countzero.co>, Marcelo Trylesinski <marcelotryle@gmail.com>, Sydney Runkle <sydneymarierunkle@gmail.com>, David Hewitt <mail@davidhewitt.io>
License: 
Location: c:\users\shock\pycharmprojects\bot\.venv\lib\site-packages
Requires: annotated-types, pydantic-core, typing-extensions
Required-by: aiogram

I'm working with Python 3.9 on Windows 11. What could be causing this issue and how can I resolve it?

Compare pydantic.__file__ between an environment where the problem happens and one where it doesn't.

The error message shows the path of the pydantic module, and it's not the one in your venv.  I imagine that is the problem.

Thanks for the help. But I can't check the files because the trial version has been spent and it won't let me go into the pro version. How do I solve this just to check the file?

There are generally two possibilities: Either you haven't activated the virtualenv, or you haven't installed pydantic into the virtualenv. I'd suggest taking pycharm out of the picture and just using command-line tools to troubleshoot -- once you know that it works correctly when you have a particular virtualenv activated you can worry about making sure pycharm activates that virtualenv; but first make it work without the IDE, so that if you have more problems when you introduce the IDE that's only one thing to debug.

try
pip install --upgrade pydantic

it worked for me (old versions were pydantic_core-2.14.6 and pydantic-1.9.1)
